# adding a search in a MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

Im trying to add a filter to a MVC with a multiple LINQ query that i got from  [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339737/linq-select-from-multiple-tables) and i want to make a filter like "add Genre" on this which is a dropdownlist [Tutorial](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/237/adding-search) if i take off the parameter from the function of brand (i do get my dropdownlist working)  And the thing is that im not sure, because in the table i need to filter brand is a number (so i think i need to pass that parameter as integer), however i get an error

> "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'brand' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(System.String, System.String, System.String, System.Nullable`1[System.Int32], Int32)' in 'BDInventario.Controllers.ArticulosController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters"

Below is my code

```
Function Index(ByVal sortOrder As String, currentFilter As String, ByVal searchString As String, page As Integer?,brand as Integer) As ActionResult

        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder
        ViewBag.NameSortParm = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder), "name_desc", String.Empty)

        If Not searchString Is Nothing Then
            page = 1
        Else
            searchString = currentFilter
        End If
        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString
        Dim brandList As New List(Of String)
        Dim brandQuery = From a In db.Articulos
                         Join m In db.Articulo_brand On a.brand_id Equals m.brand_id
                         Order By m.desc_brand
                         Select m.desc_brand


        brandList.AddRange(brandQuery.Distinct)

        ViewBag.brand = New SelectList(brandList)



        Dim articulos = From m In db.Articulos Select m

        Select Case sortOrder
            Case "name_desc"
                articulos = articulos.OrderByDescending(Function(s) s.descripcion)
            Case Else
                articulos = articulos.OrderBy(Function(s) s.articulo_id)
        End Select


        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) Then
            articulos = articulos.Where(Function(Inventario_ADO) Inventario_ADO.descripcion.Contains(searchString))

        End If
```

I think my error is in this section

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(brand) Then
            articulos = articulos.Where(Function(m) m.brand_id.Equals(brand))

        End If
        Dim pageSize As Integer = 50
        Dim pageNumber As Integer = If(page, 1)

        Return View(articulos.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize))

    End Function
```

Any help or tips would be really apreciated

Comment: Your parameter `brand as Integer` must be an `Interger` and not `Nothing`. If you getting that error its because your not passing the correct value, but you have not shown how you pass the value so impossible to help.

Comment: I think this is what you are asking me about    
    `@<p> Marca: @Html.DropDownList("brand", "All")
    Buscar: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", TryCast(ViewBag.CurrentFilter, String))
        <input type="submit" value="Filtrar" /></p>
    End Using`

or this.. i think 

`Page @IIf(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber, 0, Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, Function(page) Url.Action("Index",
                  New With {page, .sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, .currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter}))`

Comment: You need to put you code in the question, not in comments (and no where in `@Html.PagedListPager()` do you pass a value for `brand`, hence the error

Answer (score 0):

The error is because your brand parameter must be a nullable integer, like the page parameter is.

Also, I would do the ordering after the filtering. And you use ViewBag a lot, why not a ViewModel?