# Select multiple column in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am very stuck and hope your help.

How to write

```
select table1.*, table2.column1 as name
```

in linq?

I tried:

```
select new { table1, name = table2.column1 })
```

but it's output is splitted, eg:

```
table1:{address:valueOfAddress, religion:valueOfReligion, columnN:valueofColumnN}, name: valueOfName
```

I want the output like:

```
address:valueOfAddress, religion:valueOfReligion, columnN:valueofColumnN, name: valueOfName
```

thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linq. Select from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339737/linq-select-from-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 1):

I think solution will be like this,

```
var result = from t1 in table1 
             from t2 in table2
             where condition // if there is any condition to fetch records 
             select new { address = t1.address, religion=  t1.religion,columnN = t1.columnN, Name = t2.name };
```

**UPDATE**

**JsonConvert.SerializeObject()** Serialize the newly created object using linq into json and resolve the issue your are facing.
I hope you like my answer
Thanks

```
class Employee
{
    public string employeeID;
    public string Name;
    public string eventName;
 
    public Employee(string eID, string eName, string eEvents)
    {
        this.employeeID = eID;
        this.Name = eName;
        this.eventName = eEvents;
    }
}

class Event
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    public Event(int _id,string _name)
    {
        id = _id;
        name = _name;
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
        employees.Add(new Employee("PALI_e1", "Parvez Ali", "FOOTBALL"));
        employees.Add(new Employee("AALI_e2", "Ashik Ali", "FOOTBALL"));
        employees.Add(new Employee("AALI_e3", "Aftab Ali", "CHESS"));
        employees.Add(new Employee("AALI_e4", "Arif Ali", "CRICKET"));

        List<Event> courses = new List<Event>();
        courses.Add(new Event(1,"FOOTBALL"));
        courses.Add(new Event(2,"FOOTBALL"));

        var result = from l1 in employees
                     from l2 in courses
                     where l1.eventName == l2.name
                     select new { l1, l2.name };

        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}
```

[Here is expected output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKGdr.png)

Comment: I want to select *, not column by column. It's hard for us if our column is too much.

Comment: Using JsonConvert.SerializeObject() you can change the new created object using linq into json it will be similar to your expected output,